# Convert number stored as text data type to int

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a database that is a result of an import.  The database is a deliverable, I did not do the import myself, nor do I have access to the original data to do it myself.  That being said, there is an integer value that was imported to a text datatype.  All of the stored values are valid integers.  I keep getting:

```
Explicit conversion from data type text to int is not allowed.
```

if I try to change the field data type in the table.  I have also created a new INT field in the table and tried to update it based upon the value in the TEXT field, but I receive the same error.  Lastly I tried to create a new table and tried to insert the old values but cannot convert or cast to the int successfully.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This seems to work: `CONVERT(INT, CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX),myText))`

**Edit:**

I'm not totally sure of what's the best choice for the inner conversion... Choosing either `VARCHAR(N)` with `N > 10` or `VARCHAR(MAX)` has the advantage of not preventing an overflow by truncating (assuming the overflow is the preferred behavior in that case).

Also, the conversion to `INT` seems to treat leading spaces as zero.  So `VARCHAR(MAX)` reduces the chance of erroneously getting zero.  E.g.:

```
CREATE TABLE #foo ( bar TEXT )

INSERT INTO #foo
VALUES ('                                                 10')

SELECT CONVERT (INT, CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX),bar)) FROM #foo -- 10
SELECT CONVERT (INT, CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),bar)) FROM #foo -- 0
```

Probably the best thing is to do some validation to make sure the input meets whatever your requirements are.

Comment: You should include a length on the `varchar`

Comment: Ugh, [varchar without length](https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length.aspx)? Also don't you think you should use a `CASE` expression to avoid problems converting words like `ugh`?

Comment: Updated, to add a length.  Yes, it will fail as written when the text is non-numeric ... although the OP said it was always numeric, still better to check.  But I figured keep the answer simple and let the OP modify as needed -- I'm not sure what default value he'd prefer, for one thing.

Comment: @TimGoodman `MAX` isn't a length, it's an entirely different data type.  You invite issues with this method.  Since you are converting to an `int` why not choose the max characters in the `int` data type?

Comment: It's still a data type that is convertible to int, though.  Are you downvoting because my comment was inaccurate?  Actually, the original answer using VARCHAR works OK, because it defaults to VARCHAR(30), which is more than enough for an int.  I could specify 30, but then it will succeed if it has 30 numbers and then a letter, where probably this should fail.  VARCHAR(MAX) won't truncate characters that would cause it to fail, and is arguably better.

Comment: If anyone has an opinion on what a better choice would be, feel free to suggest.  Like I said, VARCHAR(MAX) has the advantage of things that should overflow or fail the conversion don't succeed just because of truncation.

Comment: Technically I suppose if I used VARCHAR(30) and had 30 numbers and a letter it would still fail because of overflow, but I don't like the idea that characters are getting truncated before the conversion to INT.  I *really* don't like the idea of truncating it to only the number of digits in an INT, unless that's really the intended behavior.  E.g. `'1000000000000'` gets converted to `1000000000`

Comment: @JNK: One more thing, using `VARCHAR(MAX)` will work for text with leading spaces. `'                      10'` gives 10, which is probably what's intended.  Whereas using `VARCHAR(10)` converts this to zero, which is almost certainly not what's intended.

Comment: @TimGoodman I wasn't aware of the leading space issue.  I get the same results from both testing in SQL Server 2008r2 so this may be version specific?  Regardless, using `MAX` for this is a bad idea, but it's an all-around bad design so I guess it's immaterial.  Make an edit and I'll remove the DV.

Comment: `Operand type clash: int is incompatible with text`

Answer (score 6):

TextValue to Int direct Conversion is not possible, so

1. convert TextValue to varchar(max)
2. varchar(max) to int or bigint

### Example :

```
convert(int, (convert( varchar(max),'TextValue'))) as ColumnName
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert text type to varchar(x), after that you can cast or convert to int. To avoid double convert i prefer cast.

```
CAST(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50),CONFIG_VALUE) AS INT)
```

Full example:

```
DECLARE @age int;

SET @age = (SELECT CAST(CONVERT(varchar(50),@yourTextVarHere) AS INT))
SELECT @age
```