# Convert Text to INT in SQL

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

`sm_Value` is a `TEXT` column which I need to convert to `INT`.

Being the fact that only two people will mess with this table, the column will be numerical (humor me)

I'm getting this error message:

> Msg 206, Level 16, State 2, Procedure User_Password_Date_Interval_Check, Line 10
>   Operand type clash: text is incompatible with int

I have tried:

```
SELECT CONVERT(INT, sm_Value)) 
FROM Setting_Misc
```

But I still get the error.

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sysobjects 
           WHERE type = 'P' AND name = 'User_Password_Date_Interval_Check')
BEGIN
    PRINT 'Dropping Procedure User_Password_Date_Interval_Check'
    DROP  Procedure  User_Password_Date_Interval_Check
END
GO

PRINT 'Creating Procedure User_Password_Date_Interval_Check'
GO

CREATE Procedure User_Password_Date_Interval_Check
    @ua_pk uniqueidentifier
AS
    DECLARE @PasswordExpireDays INT

    SELECT 
        CONVERT(INT, CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), sm_Value)) 
    FROM Setting_Misc

    SELECT
        @PasswordExpireDays = COALESCE(sm_Value,0)
    FROM
        Setting_Misc AS sm
    INNER JOIN
        Syndicates As syn ON sm.syn_fk = syn.syn_pk
    INNER JOIN
        Company As c ON c.syn_fk = syn.syn_pk
    INNER JOIN
        User_Accounts As ua ON ua.c_fk = c.c_pk
    WHERE 
        sm.sm_Setting = 'PasswordExpireDays'
GO

GRANT EXEC ON User_Password_Date_Interval_Check TO WEB
```

Comment: why are you converting it to varchar(max) first?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert number stored as text data type to int](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15346002/convert-number-stored-as-text-data-type-to-int)

Comment: `@PasswordExpireDays` seems to be where your error is so just convert it like `@PasswordExpireDays = COALESCE(CONVERT(INT,CONVERT(varchar(max),sm_Value)),0)`

Comment: I read it on another forum.  Of course I can't find the link.  I did try it without converting it to varchar first.  I have also tried CAST

Comment: @dfundako, that's the one!  Thanks!  I tried the varchar convert because of that question, after I tried a direct CONVERT(INT, sm_Value) first

Comment: @KevinFischer did you do the same conversion when you try and set `@PasswordExpireDays`

Comment: @scsimon, are you talking about my VB.Net code?  it's set up as Integer on the return

Comment: @KevinFischer no... here `SELECT @PasswordExpireDays = COALESCE(sm_Value,0)
    FROM
        Setting_Misc AS sm`

Comment: @scsimon, no,  I only convert in the previous SELECT statement

Comment: @KevinFischer your error is going to be on this line, not the other select you did the conversion on. As you'll notice the error states it's an operand error... you don't use an operand in your initial select.

Comment: It also states that it's on Line 10, which is above the CREATE

Comment: I guess my question would be then, my first SELECT statement is meant to convert sm_Value to INT and keep it that way so I can use it in the second SELECT statement.  Is that not the case?

Comment: Almost anything in the `SELECT` statement will error out on the line that `SELECT` it actually written. Error lines can be super deceiving in SQL, especially in `SELECT` blocks.

Comment: @scsimon, thank you for the SQL heads up.  I very rarely dabble in SQL

Comment: No worries @KevinFischer but if you change that one line you should be fine.

Comment: ....but, but I need it.  my previous question:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40999928/stored-procedure-if-then-statement

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129944/discussion-between-scsimon-and-kevin-fischer).

Comment: I am surprised that not one person mentioned that the text datatype has been deprecated for over a decade now. And of course the decision to use text to store numerical data is not a good choice to start with.

Comment: I read that while researching this issue.  Granted, this database is quite old

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must do the conversion where you are setting your variable.

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sysobjects 
           WHERE type = 'P' AND name = 'User_Password_Date_Interval_Check')
BEGIN
    PRINT 'Dropping Procedure User_Password_Date_Interval_Check'
    DROP  Procedure  User_Password_Date_Interval_Check
END
GO

PRINT 'Creating Procedure User_Password_Date_Interval_Check'
GO

CREATE Procedure User_Password_Date_Interval_Check
    @ua_pk uniqueidentifier
AS
    DECLARE @PasswordExpireDays INT
    --This conversion doesn't cascade down to the next SELECT statement
    SELECT 
        CONVERT(INT, CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), sm_Value)) 
    FROM Setting_Misc

    SELECT
        --Here is what has to change
        --@PasswordExpireDays = COALESCE(sm_Value,0)
          @PasswordExpireDays = CONVERT(INT, CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), sm_Value)) 
    FROM
        Setting_Misc AS sm
    INNER JOIN
        Syndicates As syn ON sm.syn_fk = syn.syn_pk
    INNER JOIN
        Company As c ON c.syn_fk = syn.syn_pk
    INNER JOIN
        User_Accounts As ua ON ua.c_fk = c.c_pk
    WHERE 
        sm.sm_Setting = 'PasswordExpireDays'
GO

GRANT EXEC ON User_Password_Date_Interval_Check TO WEB
```

Comment: Ha i wouldn't go that far @KevinFischer but glad to help

Comment: and just for official purposes, it works.  no errors